# Windows explorer Column properties

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, filesystems

My OS : Windows 10

In windows explorer, there are hundreds of properties including filename, type, size, modified date. Define them *column properties*.

It seems most of *column properties* are stored separately from file content.

Is there any *column properties* that really analyze file content, to pass information to windows explorer?

Comment: I suspect not. Those that are stored as file contents will only be read when the file changes (and is saved) at which point explorer knows the file has been updated and will reread those properties.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I edited my question ; removed "(in real time)". The term seems to be misleading my real purpose.

Comment: That doesn't change my comment.

Comment: Your question really doesn't make sense. When the file is created or modified explorer will read the disk and the file to find out the values for all the column properties. Some of those properties are already stored on the disk separately from the file, for example last modified date/time. Others will require the file to be read, for example an audio file bit rate.

Comment: The column properties don't analyze anything as they are display fields.

Comment: Does windows explore really read file content of a music file to figure out "audio file bit rate"? I mean the head of the file. I didn't know it.

Comment: How else is it going to get that information?

Comment: I thought such information(bit rate) is stored separately from file content, just like modified date.

Comment: Explorer will only display information that is readily available in the file headers. It doesn't need to read the whole file (except in the case of images when it needs a thumbnail for some views)

Comment: Thank you! now I understood it.

Comment: Its different now but in the past when you hovered over a folder it would calculate for a two seconds the file tree size, it would increase every two seconds you hovered. Now it hides the cumulative size until it has the final size.